# Getting unusual error while training a model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am following the beginner's deep learning tutorial series by Sentdex. While training the model using `python .\model.py`, the following error is being thrown:

```
2022-01-29 19:39:03.518539: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-01-29 19:39:03.519272: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
(70, 70)
2022-01-29 19:39:11.738598: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2022-01-29 19:39:11.738714: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2022-01-29 19:39:11.742605: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: AishikWindows11
2022-01-29 19:39:11.742901: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: AishikWindows11
2022-01-29 19:39:11.747739: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming-on-Linux\Ml\Cats and Dogs Classifier\model.py", line 101, in <module>
    model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=6, validation_split=0.3, callbacks=[tensorboard])
  File "C:\Users\ujana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\ujana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1482, in train_validation_split
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: `validation_split` is only supported for Tensors or NumPy arrays, found following types in the input: [<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>,
```

and this syntax of `<class 'int'>` goes on and on while coming to a sudden stop, without any other error being thrown. I tried tracking whether my model is training properly using tensorboard, but it said that no model was training at that time. Ultimately the model is not training. What to do?

Below is the code for `create_data.py` which pre-processes the data and saves them into their respective .pickle files

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
import random
import pickle

DATADIR = "path to the images"
CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]
IMG_RESOLUTION = 70

training_data = []

def create_dataset():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
        images = os.listdir(path)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in images:
            try:
                old_img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_img_array = cv2.resize(old_img_array, (IMG_RESOLUTION,IMG_RESOLUTION))
                training_data.append([new_img_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass

create_dataset()

random.shuffle(training_data)

X = []
y = []

for features,labels in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(labels)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_RESOLUTION, IMG_RESOLUTION, 1)

pickle_out = open("training_data/X.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

pickle_out = open("training_data/y.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

Below is the code for `model.py`

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation,Dropout, Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import pickle
import time
import tensorflow as tf

NAME = f"Cats and Dogs Classifier {time.time()}"

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=f"logs/{NAME}")

X = pickle.load(open("training_data/X.pickle", "rb"))
y = pickle.load(open("training_data/y.pickle", "rb"))

X = X/255.0
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))

model.add(Flatten()) 

model.add(Dense(256))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))


model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=6, validation_split=0.3, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

Comment: I know this might be a stupid comment but have you tried to convert given list into numpy arrays using numpy.arrays()

Comment: @Prats Yes I have converted the feature list X into a numpy array and reshaped it..but I haven't converted the label list y into np array.